# After saving a png file from Base64, the result file produces a different Base64 string

Tags: vb.net, image, base64, png

I have this page which has a wysiwyg editor and it allows our partners to customise their profile information, producing html which will be rendered into our marketplace.

It wasn't long before our partners got creative and started bloating our html with heaps of embeded images in Base64, making an otherwise 100kb page to be 3mb+.

The coder (me) jumps in with a wicked idea of getting this Base64 image, save it to the partner image folder (a structure we already have in place and works just fine) and replace the code with a proper image link from our repository.

All works well, but I know for a fact that the partner uses word to create a profile html and past to our wysiwyg editor. So chances are they stored these documents and when they feel like changing something, they will change their document and past it in the wysiwyg.

It shouldn't be a problem anymore, because foreseeing that I had also coded to check in that image doesn't exist in the image folder before I actually save it based on the Base64 provided, which is the problem I'm facing now.

It works really well for jpg files. I get the Base64 code, check the files in the folder, read their bytes and convert to a Base64 and I aways find the file which corresponds to that Base64 provided by the partner.

Now with png files, even though I save a Base64 as an image file on disc, that same image file when from the disc and converted to a Base64 produces a slightly different Base64 string, which is not letting me know whether I already saved that Base64 before, creating a new copy of the same file every time.

Here is the code that saves the image based on the original img tag:

```
embededImages.ForEach(Sub(imageContainer)

                                  Dim image As Image
                                  Using ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(imageContainer.ImageBase64String))
                                      image = Image.FromStream(ms)
                                      image.Save(String.Concat(imageFolderPath, "\", Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), ".", imageContainer.ImageExtension))
                                  End Using

                              End Sub)
```

Now here's the code that reads the image into a Base64 string and tries to match any of them with the Base64 string I'm processing at the moment:

```
imagesOnDisc.ForEach(Sub(imagePath)

                                      Dim currentFileBase64String = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath))

                                      If currentFileBase64String = embededImages(i).ImageBase64String Then

                                          imageFound = True

                                          Return

                                      End If

                                  End Sub)
```

Does anybody know of a particular way .NET saves png images that causes them to become a different Base64 string when the process is reversed?

I tried several images and the result is always the same: if it's a jpg image, the Base64 I save is the exact same one I read afterwards, while png files I tried several different files with the same wierd result and also iteratively replacing the Base64 in the source code of the wysiwyg editor with one from the file that was just created, and I always get a different Base64 string back.

Comment: Are you sure you are comparing the same files? You compare "imagesOnDisk" with "embededImages(i)" maybe the files in each collection are not sorted the same.

Comment: I cannot imagine comparing B64 strings is either efficient or fast.  I'd implement an actual image comparison (like maybe AForge or EmGuCV) ir maybe this [Simple image comparison in .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/374386/Simple-image-comparison-in-NET) will work.  More simply you could compare the byte arrays and determine a diff threshold to determine a new image. Comparing the arrays from `File.ReadAllBytes` to the array from a `img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png)` on the same img file gives 6 diffs.  Something like that with some threshold might be faster.

Comment: @the_lotus I am definitely not comparing the same files. Maybe I haven't been clear describing the problem: The user inputs a Base64 image embeded in the HTML. Then I save that Base64 string in a file and store it. If the user eventually tries to save the same Base64 image again, I need a way to know I already saved that exact Base64 string so I can just get the file I saved previously (hence the comparison between imagesOnDisc and embededImages) and change the HTML accordingly.